# How to clear a list of type class

Tags: c#, class, variables

i have a List which get's and set's data from/to my class "Type" after a specific condition is fulfilled i want to clear all the variables value's that have been gathered here's my code

```
List<Type> Win = new List<Type>();
void Check(int a)
{
    if (a>10)
    {                      
        Win.Add(new Type() { Power = 10 + a * 100, Current = 1 });
    }
    if(a<10)
    {
         Win.Add(new Type() { Power = 10 + a * 100, Current = 1 });
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class Type
{
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int Current { get; set; }
}
```

And like this it will always enter the 2 if's at least once because I'm giving him a parameter "a" and a will change let's say 5 times and it will get a lot of different values.How can i clear the entire "Type.Power" and "Type.Current" variables or just clear the entire list "Win" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear the entire list "Win""?

Comment: clear the entire list "Win" means remove all data inside thought that it's obvious i already have an answer below check it out

Comment: Side note: If `a == 10`, neither `if` gets executed. Also, the bodies of both `if`s are the same. You could just do `if (a != 10) {...}`.

Comment: that's just a sample code I'm not really using the if statement's shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To empty the entire list, you can use [.Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Win.Clear();
```

To reset all instances of `Type.Power' and 'Type.Current' per instance in your list, you would need to iterate the list and update the members to their default value 0.

```
Win.ForEach(x => 
    {
        x.Power = 0;
        x.Current = 0;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response !